# BSS section and clearzi

Tags: assembly, arm, startup

I know, that BSS section of a program stores global uninitialized variables. So why would I (inside startup code in branch instruction "`clearzi`") have to check if this section size equals "`0`" and then continue? I found this part of a startup code and this is what i need to understand.

```
    LDR   r0, =__gnu_bssstart
    LDR   r1, =__gnu_bssend
    MOV   r2, #0

clearzi:
    CMP   r0, r1
    BEQ   clearzi_exit
    STR   r2, [r0]
ADD   r0, r0, #4
    B clearzi

clearzi_exit:
```

This is just a small part of a startup code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code snippet clears the BSS section. It translates to

```
for (int* p = __gnu_bssstart; p < __gnu_bssend; ++p) *p=0;
```

If the size is zero, the condition is never true and so the initialization part is skipped.

Comment: I understand **how** this function checks if the end of a BSS section equals  the start of a BSS section, But i don't know **why** would anyone go and check this? **Why** is this so important? Is it possible, that this is how we check if the program has just started, because at atartup there are no initialized variables which are allways held in BSS section?

Comment: This architecture guarantees that the BSS is cleared before program start. This is to guarantee that if a program reads from an variable located in BSS before writing to it gets a zero back.

Comment: @71GA Besides, this is not a check if the BSS is zero size. This is a loop, which is not executed if the BSS is zero sized.

Comment: Oh i see and understand now. Thank you.